# Version 2 python Azure Functions are not visible after deployment with Pulumi because of imports

Tags: python, azure-functions, pulumi, infrastructure-as-code

I'm using Python and Pulumi to deploy version 2 Azure Functions with Python runtime v4 and Linux OS. The functions I want to create are HTTP triggered and have some additional functionality including database calls and some extra configs. The structure of the folder I am using:

[image]

Initially I tried to deploy an example function (taken from [here](https://www.pulumi.com/templates/serverless-application/azure/) after adapting the example to version 2) everything works fine but when I add imports (from another Python module because I want my code to be clear and organized) the functions are not visible after deployment. My functions are version 2, so they are declared in the same file using decorators. After searching I saw the following options:

- declare additional functions in additional_functions.py using
  blueprints as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level&pivots=python-mode-decorators#alternative-entry-point) -not necessary an option for me
  because I don't need additional routes inside my app
- I tried to pack my additional functions inside a custom python
  package, based on a .whl file. I added the .whl file in the folder and the dependency in requirements.txt. I did the deployment, the functions are still not visible
- the third option is to declare the additional functions as internal functions
  inside the function app - not necessary a good practice, I want my code modular

I can show a limited code snippet I have used. The main file:

```
    import pulumi
    import pulumi_azure_native as azure
    
    resource_group = azure.resources.get_resource_group(...) # get existing resource group
    
    account = azure.storage.get_storage_account(...) # get existing storage account
    
    primary_key = pulumi.Output.all(resource_group.name, account.name).apply(
        lambda args: azure.storage.list_storage_account_keys(resource_group_name=args[0], account_name=args[1])
    ).apply(lambda accountKeys: accountKeys.keys[0].value) # get connection string to storage account
    
    
    app_container = azure.storage.BlobContainer(
        "container-name",
        account_name=account.name,
        resource_group_name=resource_group.name,
        public_access=azure.storage.PublicAccess.NONE,
    ) # create a storage container
    
    
    app_blob = azure.storage.Blob(
        "blob-name",
        account_name=account.name,
        resource_group_name=resource_group.name,
        container_name=app_container.name,
        source=pulumi.FileArchive("."), # upload current folder, including the .whl file
    ) # upload the serverless app to the storage container
    
    
    signature = (
        pulumi.Output.all(resource_group.name, account.name, app_container.name)
        .apply(
             ....
            )
        )
        .apply(lambda result: result.service_sas_token)
    ) # create a shared access signature to give the function app access to the code
    
    
    plan = azure.web.AppServicePlan(
        "plan",
        resource_group_name=resource_group.name,
        kind="Linux",
        reserved=True,
        sku=azure.web.SkuDescriptionArgs(
            name="Y1",
            tier="Dynamic",
        ),
    ) # create service plan
     
    app = azure.web.WebApp(
        "app",
        resource_group_name=resource_group.name,
        server_farm_id=plan.id,
        kind="FunctionApp",
        site_config=azure.web.SiteConfigArgs(
            linux_fx_version="PYTHON|3.11",
            app_settings=[
                azure.web.NameValuePairArgs(
                    name="FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
                    value="python",
                ),
                azure.web.NameValuePairArgs(
                    name="FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
                    value="~4",
                ),
                azure.web.NameValuePairArgs(
                    name="WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE",
                    value=pulumi.Output.all(
                        account.name, app_container.name, app_blob.name, signature
                    ).apply(
                        lambda args: f"https://{args[0]}.blob.core.windows.net/{args[1]}/{args[2]}?{args[3]}"
                    ),
                ),
                azure.web.NameValuePairArgs(
                    name="AzureWebJobsStorage",
                    value=pulumi.Output.all(
                        account.name, primary_key
                    ).apply(
                        lambda args: f"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={args[0]};AccountKey={args[1]};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
                    ),
                ),
                azure.web.NameValuePairArgs(
                    name="AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags",
                    value="EnableWorkerIndexing"
                ),
                azure.web.NameValuePairArgs(
                    name="ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD",
                    value="true",
                ),
                 azure.web.NameValuePairArgs(
                    name="SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT",
                    value="true",
                ),            
            ],
            cors=azure.web.CorsSettingsArgs(
                allowed_origins=["*"],
            ),
        ),
    ) # create function app
```

And the function app:

```
import azure.functions as func
import logging
import custom_package

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)


@app.function_name(name="name")
@app.route(route="route/{arg1}/{arg2}", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS, methods=[func.HttpMethod.POST])
async def example(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('HTTP trigger function')
    res = custom_package.custom_function(arg1, arg2)    
    return func.HttpResponse(f"Success: {res}", status_code=200)
```

Are there any good practices to follow when you want to add custom functionality to functions without having to use additional routes or blueprints? The problem has been discussed but looks like there's no certain solution from Azure. Thanks!

Comment: Is the deployment success or are you getting any errors while deploying? Also Please share your `local.settings.json` and `requirements.txt`.

Comment: The deployment is successful

Comment: Have you added SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=True setting in your function app's configuration in portal?

Comment: It is added, yes. requirement.txt contains `azure-functions`, `azure-identity`, `azure-keyvault-secrets` (and some other dependencies used in my custom function) `psycopg[binary]`, `pulumi`, `pulumi-azure-native` and my `.whl` file. The `local.settings.json` not sure why is needed since I specify the `SiteConfigArgs`

Comment: Change `app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)` to `app = func.FunctionApp()`.

Comment: I tried, still not visible

Comment: Check if the function_app.py is same as shown in the [image](https://i.imgur.com/KrMA5GO.png). Also please confirm if the function is working locally.

Comment: The function is the same as the one shown in the picture. I mentioned I have a `.whl` file in the current folder. If I remove the import from the custom package inside the `function_app.py` the function is visible after deployment. I don't understand/ I don't have a solution on how to properly handle the imports from external packages (or even packages installed with `pip` for example a simple MongoDB client from `pymongo` ) inside my functions, that's the problem I'm facing

Comment: Update: I moved `import custom_package` inside the `example` function and it is visible now in the portal but it throws an error as the package is not found while calling the endpoint. My assumptions are as follows: I perform the pip install step on a Windows machine, while deploying to a Linux machine and maybe some of the dependencies was specifically downloaded for Windows or the `pip install` step is not executed before packing the current folder in the FileArchive `source=pulumi.FileArchive(".")`. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

1. To import custom packages in `Python model V2`. you can simply create a file with any name `<filename>.py` and import it in `function_app.py` using this `from <filename> import <user defined function>`.
2. To Import custom packages when you have named it `__main__.py` in the `function_app.py`. You need to add the `__main__.py` file inside a folder and import it using this `from <folder name> import __main__` and call the function inside package using `__main__.<user defined function>`.

**`Note`:**

> Make sure the `<filename>` or `<foldername>` or any file name which is important for your code is not mentioned in the `funcignore` file when deploying to azure.

Packages installed with `pip` such as `pymongo` as you mentioned in the comment, you need to mention it in the `requirements.txt` file. all the packages which are mentioned in the `requiremnets.txt` are installed in the azure function during deployment. which helps you function to run properly using required addition packages require in the main code.

Example:
[image]

**`OUTPUT`:**

1. using `<filename>.py`

**# My Directory**
[image]

**`custom_package.py`:**

```py
def get_data():
    result= "this message is from the custom package"
    return result
```

**`function_app.py`**

```py
import azure.functions as func
from custom_package import get_data
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, Vivek. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. \n  \n {get_data()}")
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

2. using `__main__.py` file name.

**#My Directory
[image]

**`__main__.py`:**

```py
def get_data():
    result= "this message is from the custom package"
    return result
```

**`function_app.py`**

```py
import azure.functions as func
from custom import  __main__
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, Vivek. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. \n  \n {__main__.get_data()}")
```

[image]

Comment: I agree this is the right way to import functions inside Azure Functions. I was able to do this as well. The problem is when adding additional libraries inside `requirements.txt` and use them in the actual code. I noticed the requirements are not installed at all (not sure how they are managed by Pulumi, in theory should be enough to install them in the venv). For example if you add `import pymongo` inside your `custom_package.py` or `function_app.py` might cause the function to break and not be visible after deployment, event if the deployment was successful and no errors are showing.

Comment: To make this clear (after several trials) I came at the conclusion it is a Pulumi issue, not an Azure issue. Pulumi is not able to install the requirements, maybe I need some additional steps/configs for that but I could not find a solution yet. Your example works because you are adding pymongo in requirements but you are not using/importing in any of your scripts

Comment: Great if you identified the cause of the issues, hope you will be able to resolve this soon.